# pool.makeClass cannot find where the class is created?

Tags: java

I tried this code in netbeans and it runs successfully. But I cant find the new class **Point 2** created. I looked in the package folder but still cannot find it. Is there something wrong with the code?

Here's the code:

```
package javaapplication1;
import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;

public class JavaApplication1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();  
        CtClass cc = pool.makeClass("Point2");
    }
}
```

Comment: "_I looked in the package folder_" It only creates the class in memory while your program is running. It doesn't write a whole new file for you, it is not a code generator.

Comment: It's _runtime_. The class is wholly in memory. Poke around a heapdump.

Comment: Don't forget, you'll probably be using fully qualified path names, i.e. `com.supercool.snoopy.Point2`